# Free Large datasets to experiment with Hadoop

Tags: resources, hadoop, opendata

Do you know any large dataset to experiment with Hadoop which is free/low cost?
Any pointers/links related are appreciated.

Preference:

- At least one GB of data.
- Production log data of webserver.

Few of them which I found so far:

1. [Wikipedia dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/)
2. http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_dumps
3. http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/

Also can we run our own crawler to gather data from sites e.g. Wikipedia? Any pointers on how to do this is appreciated as well.

Comment: datanami recently posted this list of links: http://www.datanami.com/2015/01/29/9-places-get-big-data-now/ - perhaps someone has time to convert this to a proper answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Few points about your question regarding crawling and wikipedia.

You have linked to the [wikipedia data dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/) and you can use the [Cloud9](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud9/docs/index.html) project from UMD to work with this data in Hadoop.

They have a page on this: [Working with Wikipedia](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/cloud9/docs/content/wikipedia.html)

Another datasource to add to the list is:

- [ClueWeb09](http://boston.lti.cs.cmu.edu/clueweb09/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=ClueWeb09%20Wiki) - 1 billion webpages collected between Jan and Feb 09. 5TB Compressed.

Using a crawler to generate data should be posted in a separate question to one about Hadoop/MapReduce I would say.

Comment: link "Working with Wikipedia" is dead. is this replacement http://lintool.github.com/Cloud9/docs/content/wikipedia.html ?

Comment: link for ClueWeb09 is dead. New link seems to be http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09/. It looks you need to pay for the data.

Answer (score 10):

One obvious source: [the Stack Overflow trilogy data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).  These are freely available under the Creative Commons license.

Comment: @toddlermenot - the Dumps are now hosted on the Internet Archive.  I've updated the link.  Read the reason why it changed [on this SE Blog page](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/).

Answer (score 7):

This is a collection of 189 datasets for machine learning (which is one of the nicest applications for hadoop *g*):
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

Answer (score 6):

It's no log file but maybe you could use the planet file from OpenStreetMap: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm

CC licence, about 160 GB (unpacked)

There are also smaller files for each continent: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/World